# How do I calculate Mean Squared Error of parameters alpha and beta?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, parameters

```
SeedRandom[0];

a = random variate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 3];
mle = FindDistributionParameters[
         a, 
         NormalDistribution[α, β], 
         ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"
      ]

RootMeanSquare[{{0.10393268633715443`, 0.22198702105070214`}, {2, 3}}]
```

I want to calculate the mean squared error (mse) of the two parameters alpha and beta

Comment: Are you also user @ADay ?

Comment: Table is from downloads.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2021/9949999.pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an extended comment.

You need to take a more careful look at the *Mathematica* documentation for the functions you want to use and the same for the article to be able to reproduce the mean square errors in the table.

Capitalization matters in *Mathematica*.  You want

```
a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 3];
```

rather than

```
a = random variate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 3];
```

The code

```
RootMeanSquare[{{0.10393268633715443`, 0.22198702105070214`}, {2, 3}}]
```

is not giving you what you want for 2 reasons:

(1)  You only have a single sample and to mimic what is presented in the article, you'll need multiple samples.

(2)  What you get with the nested list

```
{{0.10393268633715443`, 0.22198702105070214`}, {2, 3}}
```

is shown symbolically below:

```
RootMeanSquare[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}]
```

[image: Result of RootMeanSquare]

To obtain multiple samples and therefore multiple estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you would need something like the following:

```
nSamples = 1000;
a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], {nSamples, 3}];
mle = {α, β} /. FindDistributionParameters[#, NormalDistribution[α, β], 
      ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"] & /@ a;
bias = Mean[mle] - {2, 3}
(* {-0.00332408, -0.774355} *)
RootMeanSquare[mle]
(* {2.66969, 2.50945} *)
```

The article from which you found the table deals with a novel class of distributions more complicated than your example.  If you just want to estimate root mean square errors for parameters of standard distributions, you don't need anything mentioned in that article.  If you need to simulate samples from the distributions described in that article, then you need to read that article in more detail.

Comment: Thanks more Jim